# jquery isn not letting apex:tabpanel functionality to work

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Hi i have following code where  every thing is working fine... but when i try to add   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>` this library it is blocking all tabclicking and command button click functionlities...

```
 <apex:page standardController="case" extensions="RUnclaimedTicket" sidebar="false" tabStyle="case"  recordSetVar="search" >
        <head>
            <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/jQuery/js/jquery.js')}"  />
            <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/jQuery/js/advancedtable_v2.js')}"  />
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/jQuery/css/advancedtable.css')}"  />
          </head>

            <! ----------when i add this jquery functionality all below tabs and command buttons stopped working --- >


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

        <script>

        function checkedfield(nm, txt,field){


           if(document.getElementById(nm) != null){
            if(document.getElementById(nm).disabled == true){
                document.getElementById(nm).disabled = false;
                var check = $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
                $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val(field + check);
                check =  $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();

            }else{
                document.getElementById(nm).disabled = true;
                var check = $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
                if(check.indexOf(field) != -1)
                    check = check.replace(field,'');
                $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val(check); 

            }
           }

           if(document.getElementById(txt) != null){
            if(document.getElementById(txt).disabled == true){
                document.getElementById(txt).disabled = false;
                var check = $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
                $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val(field + check);
                check =  $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
            }else{
                document.getElementById(txt).disabled = true;
                var check = $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
                if(check.indexOf(field) != -1)
                    check = check.replace(field,'');
                $("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val(check); 
            }
           }

           return true;
        }

        </script> 


            <!----when i remove this above section everyting is working fine------------------->
    <!---But i need above functionality for further extension of my page functionality which will come here.
    <apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!updateselected}">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:inputHidden id="Checked_Item" value="{!Checked_Item}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Bulk Change" mode="edit">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="mus1" columns="1">

            <apex:pageblocktable columns="3" value="{!$ObjectType.case.FieldSets.Assignto}" var="f">
                <apex:column headerValue="Update ">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="dis_{!f}" onclick="checkedfield('{!$Component.ipField}', '{!$Component.txtField}','{!f.fieldpath}')" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Fields">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!f.Label}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Value">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!SMTPnew[f]}" id="ipField" styleclass="ipField{!f}"  rendered="{!IF(f.Type != 'string', true, false)}" required="false"/>
                    <script>
                     document.getElementById('{!$Component.ipField}').disabled = true;
                    </script>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!SMTPnew[f]}" id="txtField" styleclass="txtField{!f}" rendered="{!IF(f.Type == 'string', true, false)}"/> <!--- disabled="true"  --->
                    <script>
                     document.getElementById('{!$Component.txtField}').disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:form>
    ..--->
         <apex:form >  
         <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
        <apex:outputPanel id="SearchOverridePanelId">
          <apex:pageBlock title="Unclaimed Ticket">
           <style>
        .activeTab {background-color: #B0E2FF; color:black;font-size:17px;
        background-image:none}
        .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black;font-size:17px;
        background-image:none}
        .background { background-color: lightgrey; font-size:12px; color:black}
        </style>  

             <apex:tabPanel id="theTabPanel" selectedTab="ONE1" tabclass="activeTab" inactivetabclass="inactiveTab" contentStyle="font-size: .01px;">    
                      <apex:tab label="Unclaimed Ticket" switchType="client" ontabenter="window.parent.location.replace('/apex/UnclaimedTicketPage');" name="One1"  id="One1"   >
                      </apex:tab>
                      <apex:tab label="Claimed Ticket" switchType="client" ontabenter="window.parent.location.replace('/apex/R_ClaimedTicketPage');" name="OpenActivities2"  id="tabOpenAct2"   >
                      </apex:tab>
                      </apex:tabPanel> 
        <BR/>
                  </apex:pageBlock>  
                  </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:pageBlock >  

              /*
              .
              .
              .    i will display data in a table here.
              .
              ..  /*




                    </apex:pageBlock>  

        </apex:form>
        <script>
               function testclick() {

                         $('input[id$=search_val]').val('');




                }
        $(document).ready(function() {


        });
                </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


            if(jQuery) {
                jQuery.noConflict();
            }
            var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
            function testrun() {
            cler();
            }
            $jq(document).ready(function() {
            $jq('[id$=claim_id]').click(function() {

            //$jq('window').location.reload(true);
            //
            });
            });
        </script>      

          </apex:page>
```

can some one help me with reason for this.... when i remove above library and that block of code every thing is working fine but i cannot achieve further functionalities...

Comment: You should execute `jQuery.noConflict();` immediately after you include the jQuery script file so the `$` reference is restored to the value that existed before the script was included. But I didn't look at your page in detail so there may also be other problems.

Comment: it works perfectly ... you saved my day....thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `jQuery.noConflict()` function. There are several ways of doing this, but one easy way is to use it to rename the variable that you use to refer to `jQuery`. Do it like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery (you'd normally use '$' here)
j$( "div p" ).hide();
```

With reference to your specific code, you'd write something like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

function checkedfield(nm, txt,field){
   if(document.getElementById(nm) != null){
    if(document.getElementById(nm).disabled == true){
        document.getElementById(nm).disabled = false;
        var check = j$("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
        j$("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val(field + check);
        check =  j$("input[id$=Checked_Item]").val();
//ect...
```

You'll need this wherever you use `jQuery`. Good luck.